# Deleting handler from pipeline

Tags: handler, netty, pipeline

I am trying to delete a certain handler from my handler pipeline, but I am having trouble doing it.  When I list the handlers in the pipeline before and after, the handler that I tried to remove is still there.  So what am I doing wrong here?  Here is a code snippet.  All of this is in the startup phase.  You can see that last thing that I do is configure the pipeline factory.   I am using Netty 3.6.1.final.

```
    List<String> handlers = new ArrayList<String>();

    // list handlers in the pipeline
    try {
        handlers = this.pipelineFactory.getPipeline().getNames();
        for (int len = handlers.size(), i = 0; i < len; i++) {
          String s = handlers.get(i);
          System.out.println("Item " + i + " is " + s);
        }

    } catch( Exception e ) {}

    try {
        System.out.println("Remove hexdump");
        this.pipelineFactory.getPipeline().remove("hexdump");
    } catch( Exception e ) {
       System.out.println("error = " + e.getMessage());
    }


    try {
        handlers = this.pipelineFactory.getPipeline().getNames();
        for (int len = handlers.size(), i = 0; i < len; i++) {
          String s = handlers.get(i);
          System.out.println("Item " + i + " is " + s);
        }

    } catch( Exception e ) {}

    // Configure the pipeline factory.
    this.bootstrap.setPipelineFactory(this.pipelineFactory);
```

Here is the output:

```
Item 0 is framer
Item 1 is hexdump
Item 2 is handler
Remove hexdump
Item 0 is framer
Item 1 is hexdump    
Item 2 is handler
```

Answer (score 3):

Not sure without checking out full code, but looks like pipelineFactor.getPipeline() will always create a **new** pipeline in your case. Since its a factory, it will be creating the handlers each time. Put in one more `sysout` for `this.pipelineFactory.getPipeline()` and if you are seeing 3 different object hashcodes then this is the root cause.
Solution could be `pipeline = this.pipelineFactory.getPipeline()`, and then using the `pipeline` for adding removing etc.
Also for the record, it seems wrong usage anyway, you should be getting the pipeline from the `ChannelHandlerContext` object either in a `decode` method or a `messageReceived` method of a handler.

Comment: I do understand what you are saying about the proper usage.  I was experimenting with being able to load all my handlers in the pipeline and then removing a select few before starting to listen on the port.  I want to pass in a parameter relating to debugging that would tell me whether to remove the handlers.

Comment: I tried what you suggested (I tried that before) but nothing happened:

           ChannelPipeline cp = this.pipelineFactory.getPipeline();
           cp.remove("hexdump");

Comment: I output this.pipelineFactory.getPipeline().hashCode()) and got back
pipeline > 545768040.  When I output this.pipelineFactory.getPipeline() I got this: DefaultChannelPipeline{(framer = xxx.nettynio.VariableLengthFrameDecoder), (hexdump = xxx.nettynio.HexDumpHandler), (handler = xxx.nettynio.ListenerServerHandler)}.

Comment: Every time you are calling `getPipeline()` you are *creating a new pipeline*. You're removing a handler from a pipeline, then getting a new one; It is of course going to contain instances of all the handlers.

Comment: Ok, I follow you.  I was confused there.  If I get the pipeline, change that, and then add the Pipeline (not the PipelineFactory) to the bootstrap will that be ok?   Using "this.bootstrap.setPipeline(myNewPipeline);" instead of "this.bootstrap.setPipelineFactory(this.pipelineFactory);".

Comment: I see that using setPipeline() sets the default ChannelPipeline which is cloned when a new Channel is created.  And using setPipelineFactory() sets the ChannelPipelineFactory which creates a new ChannelPipeline for each new Channel.  Any issues with me using setPipeline() for the bootstrap?

Comment: It is an internal implementation detail you are using, so only issue might be change in future release.